# Vertical align icon to the right of header text

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I am trying to align the YouTube logo to the right of  text. Currently, the logo is displayed underneath the text - [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXonf.jpg).

Using flex for the div works, but is not responsive for tablet/mobile as the logo is presented far to the right, as opposed to right next to the text.

How could I solve this? This [here](https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logos-and-brands/512/395_Youtube_logo-512.png) is the logo I am using.

```
<div style="align-items:center;">
    <h3 style="vertical-align:middle">Our Business Opportunity</h3>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com">
        <img style="vertical-align:middle" src="assets/img/youtube_icon.png" width="35" height="35" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex works, if you don't specify the justify-content property or give it its default value "flex-start".

Try this:

```
<div style="display: flex;">
    <h3 style="vertical-align:middle">Our Business Opportunity</h3>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com">
    <img style="vertical-align:middle" src="assets/img/youtube_icon.png" width="35" height="35" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Now you only need to add some space between your h3 and the image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. On mobile, the logo is displayed on the right, as opposed to being aligned with the text. Like this: https://imgur.com/a/sCzpX7z. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @SQLNewb I see it now, but only when the viewport's width reaches 246px, which is really small. But if you still want to fix it, you can add a media query and add width: min-content; to the h3 element... By the way, I forgot to mention that Flex deals with vertical alignment too, just use the align-items property. And vertical-align:middle; is not doing anything, so you can just remove it.